# Unable to mint ERC-20 Tokens along with ERC-721

Tags: mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, chai, smartcontracts

I have the following ERC-20 Contract:

```
contract FNFToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable,     IERC721Receiver
 {
    constructor() ERC20("FNFToken", "FNT") {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }


    function onERC721Received(
        address,
        address,
        uint256,
        bytes memory
    ) public virtual override returns (bytes4) {
        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }
}
```

and the following ERC-721 Contract:

```
contract FractionalNFT is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable,IERC721Receiver {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    struct _fnft{
        uint256 tokenId;
        address fractionalToken;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => _fnft) public FNFT;

    constructor() ERC721("FractionalNFT", "FNFT") {}

    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "";
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    //is the caller of this function the owner of the NFT?
    modifier isNFTOwner(uint256 _tokenURI) {
        require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenURI));
        _;
    }

    function transferFNFToken(
        address _to, 
        uint256 _tokenURI, 
        uint256 _amount) 
        onlyOwner()
        public
      //  private
        //isNFTOwner(_tokenURI)
    {
        FNFToken _fnftoken = FNFToken(FNFT[_tokenURI].fractionalToken);
        _fnftoken.transfer(_to, _amount);

    }

    function mint(
        address _to,
        string memory tokenURI_, 
        uint256 _totalFractionalTokens
    ) external  {
        _safeMint(_to, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        _setTokenURI(_tokenIdCounter.current(), tokenURI_);

        //Create a ERC20 Token Contract for this newly minted NFT
        FNFToken _fnftoken = new FNFToken();                                      //initialize
        _fnftoken.mint(_to, _totalFractionalTokens * 1000000000000000000);   //now mint the fractional tokens and send it to the owner of this NFT           
        console.log("To", _to);
        _fnft memory fnft;                                                          //constructor
        fnft.tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();                           
        fnft.fractionalToken = address(_fnftoken);
        FNFT[_tokenIdCounter.current()]  = fnft;                                    //bind the fractional token address to this NFT token just minted
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }

        function onERC721Received(
        address,
        address,
        uint256,
        bytes memory
    ) public virtual override returns (bytes4) {
        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }
}
```

The mint function in this contract creates an ERC-721/FNFT token and mints it, then creates an ERC-20/FNT tokens through FNTToken contract and mints them to the same address as ERC-721. It then binds the ERC-20 Tokens to this ERC-721/FNFT Token.
The problem is after calling the mint function when I call the  NFTTransfer function I get the error
"Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'"

When I check the balance of the account on which the ERC-20 and ERC-721 tokens are minted it gives me 1 (only the ERC-721/FNFT is getting transferred). I have tried only minting the ERC-20/FNT but the balance of the account is 0 in this case. In the metamask the balance of ERC-20/FNT is displayed as 0.000000000..12. I think there is something wrong while passing the decimal value on this line :             `_fnftoken.mint(_to, _totalFractionalTokens * 1000000000000000000);   //now mint the fractional tokens and send it to the owner of this NFT`
But so far I couldn't find the solution.

Following is the test function to to check transfer of the tokens:

```
   describe("transferFNFToken", () => {
    it("should transfer tokens correctly", async function () {
    await contract1.deployed();
    await contract2.deployed();


    const [owner, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
    console.log("Owner Address",owner.address);
    await contract1.connect(owner).mint(owner.address, 'IPFSHASH/0',4);
    await contract1.connect(owner).transferFNFToken(addr2.address, 0,1);

    const balance = await contract1.connect(owner).balanceOf(owner.address);
    console.log("Balanace Owner Account: ",balance);
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I organized the code as below:

FractionalNFT

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.7; 

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/security/Pausable.sol";
import "./FNFToken.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract FractionalNFT is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable,IERC721Receiver {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    struct _fnft{
        uint256 tokenId;
        address fractionalToken;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => _fnft) public FNFT;

    constructor() ERC721("FractionalNFT", "FNFT") payable{}

    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "";
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    //is the caller of this function the owner of the NFT?
    modifier isNFTOwner(uint256 _tokenURI) {
        require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenURI));
        _;
    }

    function transferFNFToken(
        address _to, 
        uint256 _tokenURI, 
        uint256 _amount) 
        onlyOwner()
        public
      //  private
        //isNFTOwner(_tokenURI)
    {
        FNFToken _fnftoken = FNFToken(FNFT[_tokenURI].fractionalToken);
        _fnftoken.transfer(_to, _amount);

    }

    function mint(
        address _to,
        string memory tokenURI_, 
        uint256 _totalFractionalTokens
    ) external  {
        _safeMint(_to, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        _setTokenURI(_tokenIdCounter.current(), tokenURI_);

        //Create a ERC20 Token Contract for this newly minted NFT
        FNFToken _fnftoken = new FNFToken();                                      //initialize
        _fnftoken.mint(_to, _totalFractionalTokens * 1000000000000000000);   //now mint the fractional tokens and send it to the owner of this NFT           
        console.log("To", _to);
        _fnft memory fnft;                                                          //constructor
        fnft.tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();                           
        fnft.fractionalToken = address(_fnftoken);
        FNFT[_tokenIdCounter.current()]  = fnft;                                    //bind the fractional token address to this NFT token just minted
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }

        function onERC721Received(
        address,
        address,
        uint256,
        bytes memory
    ) public virtual override returns (bytes4) {
        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }


}
```

FNFToken

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.7; 

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";


contract FNFToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable, IERC721Receiver
 {
    constructor() ERC20("FNFToken", "FNT") {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }


    function onERC721Received(
        address,
        address,
        uint256,
        bytes memory
    ) public virtual override returns (bytes4) {
        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }
}
```

It is throwing the following error:

> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason
> provided by the contract: "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance".
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

Probably solution must be like in the following link

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/erc20-transferfrom-fails-erc20-transfer-amount-exceeds-balance/16854